# /bin/sh VS. /bin/bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operators

Is this (bash):

```
if [[ ( $month == 03 || $month == 10 ) && $weekday = "Sun" && $day > 24 ]]
```

the same as (shell):

```
if [ $month -eq 03 ] || [ $month -eq 10 ] && [ $weekday = "So" ] && [ $day -gt 24 ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're almost equivalent, except that the grouping is different. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the `sh` version is equivalent to

```
if [[  $month == 03 || ( $month == 10  && $weekday = "Sun" && $day > 24 ) ]]
```

You need to group the `[ ... ]` commands similarly to the sub-expressions in `[[ ... ]]`:

```
if { [ $month -eq 03 ] || [ $month -eq 10 ]; } && [ $weekday = "So" ] && [ $day -gt 24 ]
```

Comment: So your 2 line is to be equated with my first above?

Comment: Yes, since it looks like that one has the desired grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the explanations given by Barmer, one big difference is that since `[` is a command, and `[[ ... ]]` is a syntactic construct, the rules about parameter expansion are different. You would see this if you set your variables to a value containing a space, i.e.

```
month='bogus value'
```

While `[[ .... ]]` evaluates correct and just returns *false*, because *bogus value* is not equal to 03, `[` would first expand `$month` and you would then end up something like

```
[ bogus value -eq 3 ]
```

which obviously produces a syntax error. Therefore, if you use `[`, it is in genral necessary to quote the variables, unless you know for sure that they can not contain a space.

Another difference is that `-eq` does numeric comparision, while == does pattern matching (wildcard expansion on the right hand side). If `month` is set to 3, `-eq` would return true and `==` would return false.

If you want to do numeric comparision in bash, you can, for instance, write

```
if (( month == 3 ))
then
   .... # springtime is coming
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, there would not be spaces in the variables so I think it would be any problem, or you think any improvement of this code from barmar in second example is necessary?

Comment: Another question `date +%a` will give me the weekday in systemlanguage correct?

Comment: Since this is a new problem (unrelated to the previous one), post a new question, please. Also, since this does not seem to be related to programming, but to **using** a program, post it in [su] instead of [so].

Comment: @Omexlu : I personally never use `[` when in bash, and I nearly always quote the variables in bash and sh, when there is a risk with spaces. As long as you know what you are doing, you can do it differently of course.

Comment: Thanks, there are only numbers and letters MON, THU and so on, i think there is no risk :)